# VSFTPD – still having permission issues

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 TLS server and I have a game server installed there. In order to install plugins and manage all my server configuration files, I had to choose for a FTP server, on this case, VSFTP.

The issue is, however, I'm able to create new files and delete existing ones. But I cannot perform these actions/have these issues:

- Deleting files only works sometimes. Most times deletion operations fail and I'm forced to use SFTP to delete them, or SSH with the `rm` command.
- I can't delete recursively files and subfolders from a main folder, sometimes after trying to delete them they become hidden files and I'm forced to use SSH to remove them with `rm -rf`
- When I upload files and folders, they copy recursively, however, with the wrong permissions, such as `266`, making me unable to edit and see the recursive files and folders unless I use my root SFTP.

How can I fix these issues? I'm almost newbie to this.

Here's my [VSFTP configuration file](http://freetexthost.com/mrdsca5n1s) (`/etc/vsftpd.conf`)

Comment: cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380864/vsftp-still-having-file-permissions-issues

Answer (score 0):

its sounds like you are using as a user with no root access, try logging in as root and see if that changes anything,  if so then you need to give your user root access so you can remove and edit files. another thing to note is you have ipv6 open in your config file,  sometimes this can cause issues if not configured correctly.

Hope this helps